# How to print an Objectified Element?

Tags: python, lxml

I have xml of the format:

```
<channel>
    <games>
        <game slot='1'>
            <id>Bric A Bloc</id>
            <title-text>BricABloc Hoorah</title-text>
            <link>Fruit Splat</link>
        </game>
    </games>
</channel>
```

I've parsed this xml using `lxml.objectify`, via:

```
tree = objectify.parse(file)
```

There will potentially be a number of `<game>`s underneath `<games>`.
I understand that I can generate a list of `<game>` objects via:

```
[ tree.games[0].game[0:4] ]
```

My question is, what class are those objects and is there a function to print any object of whatever class these objects belong to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps use

```
for game in tree.games[0].game[0:4]:
    print(lxml.objectify.dump(game))
```

which yields

```
game = None [ObjectifiedElement]
  * slot = '1'
    id = 'Bric A Bloc' [StringElement]
    title-text = 'BricABloc Hoorah' [StringElement]
    link = 'Fruit Splat' [StringElement]
```

`print(game)` shows that each `game` is an [lxml.ojectify.ObjectifiedElement](http://codespeak.net/lxml/api/lxml.objectify.ObjectifiedElement-class.html).